# TypeError: No matching declaration found after variable lookup

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I am working on a simple real estate smart contract in Solidity and I keep receiving this error during testing in Truffle. " TypeError: No matching declaration found after variable lookup". The goal is to have the seller be the one to set the price of the house only.

Here is the contract code for your reference.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;


contract HomeSale {

    address payable _buyerAddress;
    address payable _seller;
    address payable _agent;

    struct Home{
        uint _priceinBUSD;
        address _owner;
        bool _homeforsale;

    }

    Home[1] HomeDB;

    modifier onlySeller() {
        require [msg.sender == _seller];
        _;
    }
    // set price of house

    function price(uint8 _home, uint256 _priceinBUSD) onlySeller public returns (uint64){
        require(msg.sender);
        HomeDB[_home].priceinBUSD;
    }

    function getPriceofHouse(uint8 _home, uint256 _priceinBUSD) public payable returns(uint256) {
      return HomeDB[_home].priceinBUSD;
    }

    // buyer purchase home

    function buyAHome(uint8 _home) public payable returns(uint256) {
       _buyerAddress = msg.sender;

        //correct home price
        if (msg.value ==HomeDB[_home].priceinBUSD)(_home);

            uint256 finalSalePrice = msg.value/HomeDB(_home).priceinBUSD;

            _seller.transfer(msg.value);
            _agent.transfer(msg.value/100);
            return finalSalePrice;

    }

}
```

Here is my test file:

```
const HomeSaleTest = artifacts.require("HomeSale");

/*
 * uncomment accounts to access the test accounts made available by the
 * Ethereum client
 * See docs: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript
 */
contract("HomeSale", function (accounts) {

  let instance;
  beforeEach('should setup the contract instance', async () => {
    instance = await HomeSale.deployed();
  });


  it("should return the list of accounts", async ()=> {
    console.log(accounts);
  });


  it("should return price", async () => {
    const value = await instance.getPriceofHouse();


    assert.equal(value, '10000')
    });
});
```